# Conjecture that $A^{T}BA = ABA^{T}$ for any symmetric matrix $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

While trying to understand the Kalman filter, and by experimentation with Python I came up with the conjecture in the title.

First of all is it true? Second, if it is, how can I prove this? I would prefer a more elegant, short proof than an elementary, one, so don't avoid e.g. bilinear forms or the diagonalisability of symmetric matrices, if these things elucidate why it is true, and make the proof shorter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not it's not. For example, take $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$. Then
$$ A^TBA = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix} $$
but
$$ ABA^T = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: What do you call a matrix such that $AA^{T} = A^{T}A$?

Comment: @Arkamis: A symmetric matrix has that property, but the symmetric matrices are not the _only_ ones that have it. Wikipedia gives the counterexample $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I caught that and edited the comment -- I initially assumed he was asking about the product, not the matrix $A$ itself :)

Comment: @user1176201: A _real_ matrix such that $AA^T=A^TA$ is called [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). I'm not sure if the same property over arbitrary fields has a name.